# Windows 10 - Default user privacy settings

Tags: windows, windows-registry, user

Scenario:
I have a Windows 10 machine set up with one local user account. I then want to add another user account but I want the new user account to go right to the desktop the very first time it logs in, without being required to answer the privacy questions - like "Do more with your voice" etc.

Can I "pre-define" these settings in the Default user somehow, so that all new user inherits the same settings? Or is this a group policy setting?

I don't mind modifying the registry directly to get this to work. And I don't need to omit the "This may take a few minutes" screen, I just need it to not require any user interaction during the first login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these commands as Administrator:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE" /v "PrivacyConsentStatus" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE" /v "SkipMachineOOBE" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE" /v "ProtectYourPC" /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE" /v "SkipUserOOBE" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

It might be enough just to set `PrivacyConsentStatus`.